# Can I set a predefined text content of a table cell in a CSS class?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I tried this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    td.orange : before { background: #DD5F15; content : "TRIPLE";}
</style>
```

But I believe it adds the content provided after the closing "td" tag, which is why it doesn't show up.
Basically, I just want all the "orange" table cells to just have the text "TRIBLE" inside them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

```
td.orange : before { background: #DD5F15; content : "TRIPLE";}
```

Try this (remove spaces before and after of colon `:` )

```
td.orange:before { background: #DD5F15; content : "TRIPLE";}​
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkgdk/).

Answer (score 0):

You could specify a background, or position the :before element relative.

On some elements ( i think inputs ) css3 does not allow :before, too.